# Unable to start activity in RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.setClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have set method: setClickListener() in Adapter and RecyclerView to perform when click item, it will transition to another activity.

My Recycler class:

```
public class CategoryCarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener, ItemClickListener {

RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutScroll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_category_adapter);      // activity_sgv

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
    // Loading tracks in Background Thread
    new LoadCategoryCars().execute();

    recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailListCarActivityDemo1.class);

    String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
    String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Car Id: " + car_id  + ", Price: " + price, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    i.putExtra("car_id", car_id);
    i.putExtra("price", price);

    Log.i("Car ID: ", car_id);
    Log.i("Price: ", price);

    startActivity(i);
}

// Initialize Toolbar the first time
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_icon_toolbar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onScroll firstVisibleItem:" + firstVisibleItem +
            " visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount +
            " totalItemCount:" + totalItemCount);
    // our handling
    if (!mHasRequestedMore) {
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if (lastInScreen >= totalItemCount) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScroll lastInScreen - so load more");
            mHasRequestedMore = true;
            // onLoadMoreItems();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all tracks under one album
 * */
class LoadCategoryCars extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        ...
    }    
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryCarActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading cars ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter(carsList, CategoryCarActivity.this);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all manufacturers
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
  } 
 }
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getCarData;  // getDataAdapter
ImageLoader imageThumbLoader;
private ItemClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getCarData, Context context){
    super();
    this.getCarData = getCarData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_car_info, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
    HashMap<String,String> map = getCarData.get(position);
    imageThumbLoader = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();        
    viewholder.price.setText(map.get(CategoryCarActivity.TAG_PRICE));
}
public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public NetworkImageView imageThumb;
    public TextView price;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        titleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleName);
        imageThumb = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageThumb);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
   }
 }
```

I have debug and see that there is a problem happen when build.

Logcat message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.totoroads.android.app, PID: 3676
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.totoroads.android.app/com.totoroads.android.app.CategoryCarActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.totoroads.android.app.RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.setClickListener(com.totoroads.android.app.ItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.totoroads.android.app.RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.setClickListener(com.totoroads.android.app.ItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.totoroads.android.app.CategoryCarActivity.onCreate(CategoryCarActivity.java:175)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
```

How to fix the problem? thank so much !

Comment: can you tell me why you need  recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this);  Adapter click listner  ?

Comment: I have list car of manufacturer and when user click item, it will display list child detail infomation. that is reason I want to Adapter click listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recyclerViewAdapter` is null. You are calling `recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this);`
before setting the adapter that is completing the execution of `new LoadCategoryCars().execute();`

Remove this line `recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this);`

Comment: Thank you so much, I have moved recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this); into onPostExecute() and it's worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your doing task asynchronously and then in onCreate trying to access the recycleview adapter which is yet null since task is being performed in async task therfore the adapter has to be set in onPostExecute like this:

```
public class CategoryCarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener, ItemClickListener {

RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutScroll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_category_adapter);      // activity_sgv

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
    // Loading tracks in Background Thread
    new LoadCategoryCars().execute();


}
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailListCarActivityDemo1.class);

    String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
    String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Car Id: " + car_id  + ", Price: " + price, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    i.putExtra("car_id", car_id);
    i.putExtra("price", price);

    Log.i("Car ID: ", car_id);
    Log.i("Price: ", price);

    startActivity(i);
}

// Initialize Toolbar the first time
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_icon_toolbar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onScroll firstVisibleItem:" + firstVisibleItem +
            " visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount +
            " totalItemCount:" + totalItemCount);
    // our handling
    if (!mHasRequestedMore) {
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if (lastInScreen >= totalItemCount) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScroll lastInScreen - so load more");
            mHasRequestedMore = true;
            // onLoadMoreItems();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all tracks under one album
 * */
class LoadCategoryCars extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        ...
    }    
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryCarActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading cars ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter(carsList, CategoryCarActivity.this);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all manufacturers
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Roy, as your recommend I have moved recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this); and it work perfectly :)